# Is there a way to set a window object property while preloading Electron version 26

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have been trying different solutions to no avail refactoring our Electron app to version 26.  Our older version of Electron was using the preload script to setup window properties (functions)

```
window.testFunction = (channel, params) => {
  ipcRenderer.send(channel, params);
}
```

so our embedded website can use these windows properties to communicate with Electron.

With this latest version of Electron, it is said to use contextBridge in the preload script in order to communicate between renderer and main.  I have `contextIsolation = true` and `nodeIntegration = false`.  With that, setting window properties in the preload script does not work anymore.  I was able to set the window property using `executeJavascript()` function in main (Invoked in renderer dom-ready listener), but in the embedded website seems to fire that window property function before the DOM is ready.

Is there a way I can preload that window property before Renderer executes?

Answer (score 1):

As documented it [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge), the new way to expose global variables into window object is to use the `contextBridge` api in your preload script.

In your case, preload.js would contain something like this:

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('testFunction', (channel, params) => {
  ipcRenderer.send(channel, params)
})
```

Then you should be able to call `window.testFunction(channel, params)` in your renderer.

Comment: Thanks Timur, I have setup contextBridge to make calls from renderer, but I'm needing to be able to call that window variable from our embedded website being used in the Electron app.